# Transformer hangs in recent versions of React Native when using Baobab

Tags: javascript, react-native, baobab

I started my React Native project with version 0.12.0 and Baobab. Everything worked great until React Native 0.14.2. In any version since then, the transform in the packager stops at 98% and the JS load fails.

I have used some of the advice [in this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2949) to determine that it's transforming a file in Baobab (`baobab/dist/update.js` or `baobab/dist/watcher.js` in different runs).

I have confirmed that Baobab is the issue by creating a clean React Native 0.16.0 install and only putting Baobab in it (with the required `require`)

At this stage, I'm not sure whether I should raise an issue with React Native or with Baobab, so I'm looking for advice on how to get some sort of error message that I can use to debug the issue and work out what's going wrong.

Comment: What is Baobab? What version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Worked this out myself:

By adding `debug=babel` to the environment the packager is running in, I got a huge amount of output and hidden in there was an error that `.babelrc` in the baobab package had an `optional` entry and the React Native packager doesn't understand `optional`. I deleted the `.babelrc` from the baobab package and everything works.